# Cast elements in UIElementCollection to Type of respective element

Tags: c#, wpf, generics

In an wpf-Application I want to cast the child elements of a Panel to the respective elements Type.
For example, a UIElementCollection has 3 children:
TextBox
Button
Label

If I iterate the UIElementCollection I'll get an UIElement and have to cast every element to it's Type before I can work with it.

So I tried to use a generic method, that will cast the UIElement to it's real type:

```
public static T getCastTo<T>(UIElement ele)
{                       
     return (T) (object) ele;
              
}
```

Using it by invoking

```
TextBox tb = SomeGenerics.getCastTo<TextBox>(ele);
```

gives me a TextBox as expected.

What I now want to do is using it in a loop something like

```
foreach(UIElement ele in uielementCollection) {
    SomeGenerics.getCastTo<ele.GetType()>(ele);  // or
    SomeGenerics.getCastTo<typeof(ele)>(ele);
}
```

but the compiler tells me that I can't use a variable as a Type.
Is there a way to use the generic method without specifying the Type "manually"?

Comment: To check the syntax of the rest of your method, the compiler needs to know at compile time what type the object is.

Comment: Lets say you were successful and you could cast it to the correct type without knowing what the type is. How will you successfully use that object in code if you don't know at compile time what that type will be?

Comment: I wonder if working with the ui directly is really a good way to do whatever you're trying to do.  I'd prefer to work with data in properties and datatemplate +- styling +=- triggers in the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `Enumerable.Cast`(hard cast) or `Enumerable.OfType`(also filters):

```
IEnumerable<TextBox> allTextBoxes = uielementCollection.OfType<TextBox>();
```

In general you can't use a generic methods if you know the type at runtime, generics are a compile time feature. So all you can do is to cast them to the desired type or the common base type. Then you can process them somewhere else by try-casting them to a specifiy type:

```
foreach (Control c in uielementCollection)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case TextBox txt:
            // handle TextBox
            break;

        case Label lbl:
            // handle Label
            break;
        //  ... and so on
    }
}
```